# PHP encode JSON (2 dimensional array)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am querying a table that return to fields(message_type & percentage).
I use PHP to encode the json data, here is how i do it

```
$json = array();
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
  $json[][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

output :

```
[ [ { "message_type" : "bullying",
      "percentage" : "60"
    } ],
  [ { "message_type" : "cheating",
      "percentage" : " 14"
    } ],
  [ { "message_type" : "Stress",
      "percentage" : "16"
    } ],
  [ { "message_type" : "Gang",
      "percentage" : "7"
    } ]
]
```

As you can see json_encode function is adding curly braces, quotes and the object key name.

What I want is to parse the json as two dimensional array only, here is the desired output:

```
[
  ["bullying", 60],
  ["harrassment", 9],
  ["cheating", 14],
  ["Stress", 16],
  ["Gang", 7]
]
```

I also tried to encode it manually but I could not get the result I need.

Comment: `$json[][]` --- why `[][]`?

Comment: [`$json[] = array_values($row);`](http://php.net/array-values)

Comment: @DaveRandom you solved my problem if you add it as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP's `json_encode()` uses a certain amount of magic to determine whether a given vector is encoded as a JSON object or an array, but the simple rule is this: If the array has contiguous, zero-indexed, numeric keys, it will be encoded as an array. Any other vector (object or associative array) will be encoded as an object.

Because you are using `odbc_fetch_array()`, your result rows are returned as an associative array with the keys being the column names. To get the result you want you have 3 options:

Pass the result rows through [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array-values):

```
$json[] = array_values($row);
```

Manually construct the individual arrays:

```
$json[] = array($row['message_type'], $row['percentage']);
```

Or probably the best option is to use [`odbc_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/odbc-fetch-row) instead, which will return indexed arrays straight away:

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $json[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem , thanks for the detail answer.
I also noticed json_encode remove the leading zero if the value is less than 1, for example 0.23 ---> .23   how do I avoid that?

Comment: @meda That wouldn't happen if the data was a float and `json_encode()` wouldn't do it at all, I suspect it's odbc that's doing that (although it's pretty odd behaviour for any environment). Can you show a `var_dump($json);` just before the `json_encode()` call?

Comment: here is one of the array before the encoding [12]=>array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "Sexual Harrasment[1]=>string(12) ".16638935100"}

Comment: @meda Yes, you can see that the leading zero has already been stripped off before it is passed to JSON. What is the data type of the `percentage` column in the database?