# Parsing Multidimensional Nested JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I feel like i am slightly insane, and I have certainly read the docs on this. I am completely unable to echo out various objects in a JSON array in PHP. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm ripping my hair out...

**Here is my JSON array:**

```
{
    "photos": {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 1569045,
        "perpage": 1,
        "total": "1569045",
        "photo": [
            {
                "id": "14842817422",
                "owner": "23432140@N06",
                "secret": "c37cfa1914",
                "server": "3864",
                "farm": 4,
                "title": "pizza",
                "ispublic": 1,
                "isfriend": 0,
                "isfamily": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "stat": "ok"
}
```

I know this is simple, but I can't get it right. I would like to echo out four different values.

**This is what I have been trying:**

```
$photoId = $jsonDecoded['photos']['photo'][0]['id'];
$photoSecret = $jsonDecoded['photos']['photo'][0]['secret'];
$photoServer = $jsonDecoded['photos']['photo'][0]['server'];
$photoFarm = $jsonDecoded['photos']['photo'][0]['farm'];
```

I know this seems newbie. Please help...

Best,

Comment: are there multiple photo sub-arrays ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP encode JSON (2 dimensional array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914282/php-encode-json-2-dimensional-array)

Comment: @AMB it just looks like that one. I've tried removing the single quotes, and I've tried doing it in object format with "->"

Comment: first do a json decode and store the values in $jsonDecode as `jsonDecode = json_decode('json data',true)` then your code should work.

Comment: you can add, true as a second parameter while doing json_deocode so it will create an array,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have both objects and arrays in your json, but are using array syntax in your php.

There are two ways to fix this, 1st simply set the second parameter of json_decode to true:

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

This will create a multidimentional array you can access as suggested in your question, eg:

```
$photoId = $jsonDecoded['photos']['photo'][0]['id'];
```

Alertinitivly you can use object property syntax on your existing $jsonDecoded:

```
$photoId = $jsonDecoded->photos->photo[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

if there are multiple **photo** sub arrays then you can do like this.

```
//this will create array instead of object
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($your_feed_data,true);

foreach($jsonDecoded['photos']['photo'] as $sub_array){

$photoId = $sub_array['id'];
$photoSecret = $sub_array['secret'];
$photoServer = $sub_array['server'];
$photoFarm = $sub_array['farm'];

}
```